# Save UInt8array as png in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have UInt8array, width, height of png image.
I tried to save it like this

```
const screenshot = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(await frame.exportAsync()) // figma.com/plugin-docs/api/properties/nodes-exportasync 
// passing screenshot as string over network
const uint8array = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(screenshot);
const data = Buffer.from(uint8array);
fs.writeFileSync(`${fileName}.png`, data, 'binary');
```

but this code obviously does not consider width and height.

How can I save it as png in Node.js properly?

Comment: what is `screenshot`?

Comment: `screenshot` is  new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(await frame.exportAsync()) , where exportAsync is https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/properties/nodes-exportasync

Comment: So what is `frame.exportAsync()`? Also I dont think using UTF8 strings to transfer binary data is always safe.

Comment: frame.exportAsync() returns UInt8array. Probably you right. But I also looking for a way to save png in node from UInt8array anyway.

Comment: @Lux what is the safe way by the way?

Comment: Never use utf-8 to transfer binary. I don't even know how you'd get that to work. utf-8 is a **text** encoding, not meant for binary. Use base64 if you need an ascii representation of binary data.

Answer (score 1):

As @Lux mentioned using UTF8 strings to transfer binary data is not safe, so I used conversion to base64

this works

```
var base64 = btoa(new Uint8Array(await frame.exportAsync()).reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), ''),
);

// passing screenshot as string over network
function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String: string) {
    var padding = '='.repeat((4 - (base64String.length % 4)) % 4);
    var base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');

    var rawData = atob(base64);
    var outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
        outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return outputArray;
}

const uint8array = urlBase64ToUint8Array(screenshot);
const data = Buffer.from(uint8array);
fs.writeFileSync(`${fileName}.png`, data, 'binary');
```

no need for width and height also as it is encoded in buffer.